# 403 Forbidden when playing Google Drive Video

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api, html5-video

I'm having html5 video from google drive and it stops after some time
The reason for this is

I'm accessing google drive file using download url bt download url is expired after some time so that catch error

Find My Code below

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="video" class="" 
src="https://drive.google.com/ucexport=download&id=1qSC6ySf6ZZldFRpuBx9EXvDsD-mfve1Z" 
type="video/mp4">  </video>
```

Any Solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: Are you able to copy that video and store it in your personal Google Drive? If not, this is not possible unless you know the Shared link each time your `<video>` tag is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

> 403 Forbidden

Means that the user accessing the link does not have permission to access it.  The user would need to be logged in to access it.  You can try setting the file to public but the link will probably still expire after a time.

Also there is a recent security change which may be effecting you [Resource keys](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resource-keys)

Comment: Its public Link but still it expires. Cant I set something in google drive so it should not expire?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution you can just do this

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");

video.addEventListener("ended", () => {
video.innerHTML = `<source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Ei2Af0cV9IhvES-MOhoSn96YtjlQGWXw" type='video/mp4'>`;
});
```

```html
  <video autoplay loop muted
  style="display: block; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; z-index: -2; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; background-attachment: fixed; object-fit: cover; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0;">
  <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Ei2Af0cV9IhvES-MOhoSn96YtjlQGWXw" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

```
    const video = document.querySelector("video");
    video.addEventListener("ended", () => {
    video.innerHTML = `<source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Ei2Af0cV9IhvES-MOhoSn96YtjlQGWXw" type='video/mp4'>`;
    });
```